# ul li vertical multiline - wrong position

Tags: html, css

i have html:

```
<ul>
    <li>1<br/>01<br/>001
        <ul>
            <li>1.1
                <ul><li>1.1.1</li></ul>
            </li>
            <li>1.2
                <ul><li>1.2.1</li></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2<br/>02
        <ul>
            <li>2.1
                <ul><li>2.1.1</li></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
ul { 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    list-style: none outside none;
}
li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
    min-width: 100px;
    border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tss9fLru/2/

how to align 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 2.1, 2.1.1 to top-right of his block?

Comment: vertical-align won't work with `display:block;`, you need to use `display:inline-block;` or `display:table-cell;`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal thanx. but block-width have different :-(

Comment: @BhojendraNepal http://jsfiddle.net/tss9fLru/3/

Comment: @askovpen This fiddle above have the vertical alignment you need? (Because `how to align 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 2.1, 2.1.1 to top-right of his block` it's a little unclear to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css:

```
ul { 
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    list-style: none outside none;

}
li {

    vertical-align: top;
    display: table;
    min-width: 100px;
    border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

Comment: bottom and top block have different width